# rotating user agent using Python3 and Selenium 4 chrome

Tags: python, selenium, user-agent

I was wondering if it is possible to rotate between user agents using selenium 4 and Python. My script create multiple chrome windows, but all of them get the same fake user agent. Anyone knows if at this date you can rotate selenium fake user agents between each window it creates ? 
Thank you in advance!

[image]

update : here is my updated code, even with cdp (thanks for the updated answer)i still get the same UA for every windows. Might be something wrong in my code that blocks me ?

Comment: sorry tried to add picture but did it badly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent # pip3 install fake_useragent
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={UserAgent().random}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyua.info/")

sleep(5)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": {"User-Agent": f"{UserAgent().random}"}})
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyua.info/")
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I did, but every instance created has the same UA :/

Comment: Yes me too when i stop it and run it again, but when i put like 10 instances in my script which will generate 10 instance successively, their UA is the same

Comment: What i want to do is for a nwindow get a random ua, then for n+1 window get another one different from n for n+1

Comment: even with cdp ? because apparently it should be possible under Selenium 4 as someone said in the answer you sent

Comment: It's possible with `execute_cdp_cmd`  ! please check the updated answer.

Comment: I posted an update as i still only get one random UA for X amount of chrome windows even using cdp :/ if you could check it out it would be awesome. thank you for your time, help and knowledge

Comment: Please update your question, don't post a new answer. I've tested the code on my answer and it shows a different user agent on every `driver.get()`

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. I still get the same UA tho

Comment: I don't think faking anything using Python will work guys, as websites are now recording IP addresses, so unless you run various VPN connections, none of the above will work

Comment: @Fandango68 "_don't think faking anything using Python will work guys_" - The OP didn't ask to "_fake anything_", OP asked to "_rotate between user agents_".